# Send timestamp array parameter to PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, function, timestamp

i have developed a pgplsql function to receive array of dates the return the maximum date, but its not able to call the function:

```
select 1, arcfm.array_max_date('{2022-02-03, 2022-06-05}'::timestamp[]) as max_date_time;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arcfm.array_max_date(in dates_array timestamp[])    
RETURNS timestamp    
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$    
declare         
max_date_time timestamp;    
BEGIN        
SELECT max(x) into max_date_time FROM dates_array as x;        
return max_date_time;    
END;
$$
;
```

tried calls like:
select 1, arcfm.array_max_date('{2022-02-03, 2022-06-05}'::timestamp[]) as max_date_time;

and expected the maximum date but it gives call error

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "dates_array" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function array_max_date(timestamp without time zone[]) line 5 at SQL statement

Comment: The error is happening because `dates_array` is a value but you are trying to use it as a table named `dates_array`. That will not work. See @Fastnlight's answer and my comment to make it work in the function. The `unnest()` will turn the array into a "table", actually a set of rows.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, this comment made my function work this (unnset) solved the issue of the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest()` to convert the array to a set of rows, and then use `max()` to get the maximum value:

```sql
select max(x)
from unnest('{2022-02-03, 2022-06-05}'::timestamp[]) as x;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i need a function allows me to use it inside select query,
example: select age, array_max_date(tbl1.date, tbl2.date, tbl3.date)

Comment: In that case, try using `GREATEST`: `SELECT GREATEST('2022-02-03'::timestamp, '2022-06-05'::timestamp);`

Comment: I believe what @Fastnlight was trying to get at was in the `array_max_date()` function do: `select max(x) into max_date_time from unnest(dates_array) as x`.

Answer (score 0):

The better answer as suggested by Fastnlight is by using built-in function called "GREATEST"

```
SELECT GREATEST('2022-02-03'::timestamp, '2022-06-05'::timestamp);
```

The explanation of Adrian Klaver fixed my function issue also:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arcfm.array_max_date(in dates_array timestamp[])
    RETURNS timestamp
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    declare 
        max_date_time timestamp;
    BEGIN
        SELECT max(x) into max_date_time FROM unnest(dates_array) as x;
        return max_date_time;
    END;
$$
;


select 1, arcfm.array_max_date('{2022-02-03, 2022-06-05}'::timestamp[]) as max_date_time;
```